# How do I make a transition move leading and move trailing?

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios-animations

I have a "Side-Menu" that I'm implementing in my app, however I have an issue where I can only get the side menu to slide in, but when it's removed from the view, it does an opacity transition. How do I properly set a transition such that it slides in and out from the leading edge?

```
ZStack {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation { isShowingMenu.toggle() }
        }, label: {
            Text("Button"
        })
    }
    .offset(x: isShowingMenu ? screenSize: * 0.8 : 0)
    

    if isShowingMenu {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(width: screenSize.width * 0.8)
            .transition( .move(edge: .leading))
    }
}
```

Notice that when the side-menu appears, it slides in as expected, however when I dismiss the side-menu, it just disappears instead of transitioning out. I made an attempt to use the `.asymmetric(...)` transition but it does the same thing.

```
.transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .move(edge: .leading), removal: .move(edge: .trailing)))
```

[image]

A working solution that I am using currently is to instead offset, off the screen, and bring it back when the value changes, without the condition; However, I still believe a transition should work in this instance.

```
Rectangle()
    .frame(width: screenSize.width * 0.8)
    .offset(x: baseVM.menuShowing ? 0 : (screenSize.width * 0.8) * -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing a `withAnimation`in the Button toggle.
And be aware: Transition does not correctly show in preview, but in Simulator its fine.

```
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            VStack {
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation { // here
                        isShowingMenu.toggle()
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Text("Button")
                })
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .padding()

            }
            .offset(x: isShowingMenu ? 200 : 0)
            
            if isShowingMenu {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 200, alignment: .leading)
                    .transition( .move(edge: .leading))
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I just forgot to put that in the original post. I'll edit that in now. The problem isn't the animation isn't showing, it's that it only animates when it comes in, NOT when it goes out. On it's way out, it has an opacity transition out, instead of a slide out.

Comment: yes I did understand that, with my code it is animating in and out just fine with a slide. I'm running Xcode 14.1 and Simulator iOS 16.1. I'll add a screen record.

Comment: Interesting... what is the difference with my code and this. I appear to be missing something that makes this reproducible. I'm going to have to compare to really figure it out, my question was an attempt to reduce my actual code such that it's the minimum reproducibility but I seem to have failed at that. I'll get back with more details momentarily. I suspect whatever that diff happens to be is the problem and that your answer is indeed correct.